# Postgresql ORDER BY spaces

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let say I have a table with one column, i.e.:

```
5 absolute
5.0
5.1
last
50
5 elite
edge
```

I need to order this to (using postgresql methods):

```
5 absolute
5 elite
5.0
5.1
50
edge
last
```

But if I use classic "ORDER BY column ASC" I get:

```
50
5.0
5.1
5 absolute
5 elite
edge
last
```

There are a lot of tools like substring or using, but I can't understand how they works.

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know, may be something like this:

```
with cte as (
   select col1, regexp_split_to_array(col1, ' ') as d
   from Table1

)
select col1
from cte
order by
    d[1] ~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$' desc,
    case
        when d[1] ~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$' then
            d[1]::numeric
    end,
    d[2]
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/da635/3)</kbd>**

this one splits string by spaces to array, convert first entry to numeric and sorts results by this number and remaining string

Comment: It seems to be correct, but I forgot about all string can be with just [a-z] values. So I have `invalid input syntax for type numeric:`. Please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
order by regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9\.]', '', 'g')::numeric DESC
```

It removes all character that are non-numeric (leaves only digits and the `.`) from the value and then converts it into a number. That number is then used to sort descending

The only thing is that 5.0 will be sorted after 5.1 with the above.

If you need to take values into account which don't have any digits, something like this:

```
order by 
      case 
         when regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9\.]', '', 'g') <> 
            then regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9\.]', '', 'g')::numeric
      end DESC NULLS LAST, 
      the_column DESC -- to sort the "NULL" values alphabetically
```

If you don't want to repeat the regex expression you could do something like this:

```
with clean_data as (
   select the_column, 
          regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9\.]', '', 'g') as clean_column, 
          ....
   from ...
)
select *
from clean_data
order by case 
           when clean_column <> '' then clean_column::numeric 
         end desc nulls last, 
         the_column desc;
```

Comment: It seems to be correct, but I forgot about all string can be with just [a-z] values. So I have `invalid input syntax for type numeric:`. Please see updated question

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I think that's very difficult for just postgres

Comment: @asiniy: you can always write a function that implements the above logic and then use that function in your query (which would reduce your query to `select * from some_table order by get_sort_value(the_column)`

Comment: Hm. I want to use this in Rails. How I can do this in ActiveRecord?

Comment: @asiniy: I have no idea. I don't use Rails and I avoid ORMs like the plague precisely for those problems. But using a function should be much easier than using a complicated expression.